# Periodical vs Issue?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms

I found *issues* were used on some websites like "$1 an issue". (Some magazines.)

But I found another word *periodical* was used on my vocabulary book as follows:

> The *periodical* is published every month.

Can I replace the *periodical* with *issue* here?

Appreciate your comments and replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the replacement is probably not valid.

The word *periodical* refers to a publication that is published as a series of *issues*. The relationship is similar to that between a deck of cards and an individual card.

You could say something like

```
A new issue is published every month.
```

but

```
The issue is published every month.
```

doesn't work.

What's happening is that the definite article *the* is being replaced with the indefinite article *a* to indicate that you could be talking about **any** issue and not a particular one. The adjective *new* is optional here but sounds better to my ear. It could just be

```
An issue is published every month.
```

Here, we switched to *an* which is identical to *a* in meaning but precedes words that begin with a vowel and some<sup>1</sup> words that begin with 'h'.

<sup>1 Technically I think it precedes all words that begin with an 'h' but that's sort of a dated rule in actual usage in the United States.</sup>